# querying categorymembers with wikimedia and the size

Tags: api, mediawiki

I try to get the page sizes of all category members through the wikimedia api with only one request.(or less then 10). 
I know I would get the sizes of pages by:

(1) Requesting every page separately and get the size

or

(2) A search query like this:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=physics
```

The result is several pages with the size and word count property.

Now how can I get the size and word count for a category member with a query like this or with another trick ?

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Physics
```

Any hints shared would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a category query as a generator, using `generator=categorymember` and `gcmtitle=Category:Physics`. This will execute the query action for each and every page in that category:

[`api.php?action=query
        &generator=categorymembers
        &gcmtitle=Category:Lakes
        &prop=info`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:Lakes&prop=info)

In the [docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties) you can see what properties can be used as generators: `categories`, `links` and `templates`. Also, more or less every [list module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Lists) can be used as a generator in the same fashion.

Note that parameter names are prefixed with a `g` when used for a generator, so that `cmtitle` in the example above becomes `gcmtitle`, to distinguish them from parameters to the  query action (that is applied to every page returned by the generator), `prop` and `inprop`, parameters

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much. Do you also know howto set the limit higher. So I can get 100 of entries for example ?

Comment: Just found out myself. As you described just adding a g to cmlimit -> gcmlimit. Thanks again.

Comment: Updated: `inprop` not used here.